# Make content to be placed next to the left menu instead of laying under

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/3/)

I have a frame using bootstrap. I've created the top panel and the left menu. Now I want to place the content in a `div` tag, which lays next to the left menu, and reachs to the bottom right of the main frame. But now it's laying under the menu instead of next to it. I tried every way I could think of but still fail.

Here it is :

```
<div id="pLeftMenu">
</div>
<div id="pBody">
This text is going down, but it should be laying next to the vertical buttons group 
</div>
```

css :

```
.pBody {
    float:right;
    width:80%; 
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

My idea of `pBOdy` is to create a frame which has fixed width to contains the displayed data

**UPDATE** : since I was asking, I also want to know how can I make the header, and the left menu to stay fixed, the only scrollable frame is the `pBody` which I'm failing to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your css selector `.pLeftMenu  .pBody` to `#pLeftMenu  #pBody`

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/5/

**UPDATE** if you want to make `pBody` is the only scrollable frame. change the css code like following :

```
#pHeader{position: fixed; width: 100%; top:0px;}
#pLeftMenu {position: fixed;top: 25px;}
#pBody {margin:25px 0px 0px 100px; background-color:white; border:1px solid;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/7/

Comment: Hi, it worked, Thanks alot! BTW could you take a look at my updated part at the question please?

Comment: @hoangnnm i have upgraded the jsfiddle, this version is what you wanted, http://jsfiddle.net/ettmujvg/7/